# How to translate column names to other language on grid by clicking button?

Tags: angular, angular-translate

Hello All,

I am new to angularjs and just want to know how to translate column names to other language on grid by clicking button. i could get column names with english language but don't know how to translate other language. Please throw a lamp to fix this doubts and would be better if you provide an examples with grid.

```
import { Grid } from 'src/app/models/grid';
import { TranslateService } from 'src/app/services/translate';
import { GridService } from 'src/app/services/grid.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-work-order-details',
    templateUrl: './work-order-grid.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./work-order-grid.component.scss']
  })
  export class WorkOrderGridComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private translateService){}
 WogridModel: Grid;
 ngOnInit() {
      this.WogridModel = {
      gridId: 'WorkOrder',
      displayFields: [
        { field: 'word_id', title: this.translateService.Translate('word_id'), filterable: true, _width: 210 }
           ],
      height: '500',
      pageable: true,
      commandColumn: true,
      selectionType: 'multiple',
      multiSelectId: 'worder_obj'
       };
    const body = {
      'request':
      {
      'ttFilter':
       {
         'ttFilter':
          []
       }
     }
    };
      this.woService.fetchallwo(body).subscribe(r => {
      this.WogridModel.gridRecords = r;
      this.gridService.reloadGrid.next(this.WogridModel);
    });
  }
}

/* translateService */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService as __BaseService } from '../../api/base-service';
import { ApiConfiguration as __Configuration } from '../../api/api-configuration';
import { StrictHttpResponse as __StrictHttpResponse } from '../../api/strict-http-response';
import { Observable as __Observable, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map as __map, filter as __filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
class TranslateService {
    constructor() { }

    public Translate(value): string {
    switch (value) {
    case 'word_id':
    return 'Order Id';
    }
  }
}

export { TranslateService }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pipe in the markup `{{'SOME_NAME'|translate}}`.
And for the button

```
onButtonClicked(languageKey:string):void{
  this.translateService.use(languageKey);
}
```

And it should change direct without reload of page